# how to show stream content from Guzzle response to html

Tags: php, html, laravel, html5-audio, guzzle

I try to show a stream response that have audio/wav output from api using Guzzle. this is what I did

```
  $data = array(
          'input_text' => $request->input_text,
      );
      $url = "http://abc.or/tospeech";
      $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
      $response = $client->post($url, [
          'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'],
          'body'    => json_encode($data)
      ]);

      $result = $response->getBody()->getContents();
return redirect('/home')->withInput()->with('result', $result);
```

from the code above the $result have output null but if I change the result to

```
$result = (string)$response->getBody();
```

the result will looks like this [image]

then I try to show it in html like this

```
<audio id="source" class="form-control" controls>
       <source src="{{ session('result') }}" type="audio/wav">
       Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

but nothin happen. please help is anyone knows about this. I really appreciate it.

Comment: `src` needs a URL that the data will be coming from. In your case `src` should point to the controller action that runs that code and that code should return the data directly and not redirect with the data in the session.

Comment: but my output is not URL but audio/wav. do you know how to solve this?

Comment: You need to separate this in two different routes. One that returns the view, and one that returns the audio content directly. Then in the view your audio tag will have a source the url of the other action.

Comment: do you have an example of how the route can show the audio/wav? because I don't know how to get the audio/wav content. it always null or it's not null if I show it string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have these two routes:

```
Route::get('/home', function (Request $request) {
    return view('index', [
        'input_text' => $request->input_text
    ]);
});

Route::get('/audio', function (Request $request) {
      $data = array(
          'input_text' => $request->input_text,
      );
      $url = "http://abc.or/tospeech";
      $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
      $response = $client->post($url, [
          'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'],
          'body'    => json_encode($data)
      ]);

      $result = $response->getBody()->getContents();
      return response($result, 200, [
           'Content-Type' => 'audio/wav'
      ]);
})->name('stream');
```

Then your view will be something like:

```
<audio id="source" class="form-control" controls>
       <source src="{{ route('stream', [ 'input_text' => $input_text ]) }}" type="audio/wav">
       Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

The idea here is:

1. Your initial `/home` route would stay the same (not sure how it was before, here I just have an example one).
2. There's a 2nd route that will read the audio data and and send them as a response.

This should make the audio element play the data when it's all loaded. Note that this does not allow seeking through the audio and will actually send all the audio at once. If you want to support seeking you need to make your route support [http range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) requests. There's [at least one library](https://github.com/ramsey/http-range) that is said to provide support for Laravel but this seems outdated so you may need to do additional searching.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. it really works. I don't remember if I can return response. thank you